# WebService not found facescontext in jsf

Tags: web-services, jsf

I am trying to call a managed bean inside webservice method. It throws a `NullPointerException` because `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` returns `null`.

How is this caused and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

JSF is a component based MVC framework which is executed by `FacesServlet`. That servlet is also the one responsible for creating the `FacesContext`. If your HTTP request is not served by the `FacesServlet` like as when you're using a entirely separate and standalone web service framework which is controlled by a completely different servlet, then the `FacesContext` is simply not available. The `FacesContext#getCurrentInstance()` will then return `null`.

Trying to call a JSF managed bean inside a webservice method makes no sense. It's like as in using the wrong tool for the job. Just refactor the code which you need to execute into a new and separate class which you finally just import/inject in both the JSF managed bean and the webservice class.

Comment: It's impossible to refactor the code.can i call FacesServlet and initialize facescontext ?